# How to animate(stretch & shrink) appbar(PreferedSizedWidget) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver, flutter-appbar

I'm going to implement some nice animation to sliver appbar's bottom property. So that when i pressed on the button, it should show up like fadeinDown animation. and at the next time should disappear with fadeOutUp animation.
[image]

As you can see now it is appearing  and disappearing suddenly. which is not good user experience.
Could someone help me with it? I'm having trouble to give animation to PreferedSizeWidget(appBar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this with TweenAnimationBuilder.
[TweenAnimation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TweenAnimationBuilder-class.html)

Comment: I cannot implement it with PreferedSizeWidget

Comment: you can use PreferedSize just like PreferedSizeWidget 

`PreferedSize(
    child: Container(),
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),)`

Comment: I've made it with TweenAnimationBuilder. Thanks.

Comment: it would be great, if there is any way making it with expansion tile widget. So that it would be more smooth and less expensive

Comment: Where did you add the TweenAnimationBuilder ?